# What was Manny's sin?

Tags: grim-fandango

In the game [Grim Fandango](https://www.google.com.au/search?rls=en&q=grim+fandango), we find out that the protagonist, Manuael Calavera, is working off a debt to the powers that be. Presumably, he committed a sin in his life which meant he had to work for the DoD before he would be allowed to make his 4-year journey to the 9th underworld.

Is it ever explained, in the game or out (interviews, publications etc.) what it was that Manny did?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a great question, but I'm not sure there's a definitive answer, other than "we don't know".

According to the character's page on the [Grim Fandango wikia](http://grim-fandango.wikia.com/wiki/Manuel_%22Manny%22_Calavera):

> Almost nothing is known about Manny's time in the Land of the Living. Periodically throughout the game, *Manny states he doesn't know what sin he committed* [emphasis mine] that got him stuck at the Department of Death, but that he is willing to work his time off regardless. In Year 1 he says that he has none that he wishes to visit during the Day of the Dead.

My best guess - it's left intentionally unanswered as it gives him an air of tragic mystery (even *he* doesn't know) and is actually irrelevant to the story anyway.